# No instruction in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let us say i have a code like this ternary:
`element ? doSomething() : doNothing;`, I wish to know if there is a keyword to say do nothing using this ternary instruction. That is what should I put to say do nothing without using an empty function. I tried putting just the semi-colon it gives me an error.

Comment: If you have no intention of using the value of this expression, then `if` is the correct choice.  If you want to make use of the value, you need to provide the `:` part.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) instead.

```
element && doSomething();
```

Comment: This approach is neatly better.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `if` if you have no intention of using the `else`-part of the shorthand syntax anyway.

```
if (element) doSomething ();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the ternary you could do:

```
element ? doSomething() : null;
```

This is probably the best approach as you wouldn't want to return a boolean or some other value in the place of null.

It will return null if the expression is not true, which allows you to check for the null value elsewhere if you have assigned it to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use [***Logical AND(`&&`)***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) instead of `ternary` operator!

```
element && doSomething();
```

***`expr1 && expr2`***, Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to **`false`**; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns **`true`** if *both operands are true*; otherwise, returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use ternary expression:

```
element ? doSomething() : true
```